# How can i minify my css with gulp-clean-css?

Tags: node.js, gulp, package.json

I have a problem with gulp-clean-css in my gulpfile.babel.js file

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.8.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9.7.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "browser-sync": "^2.26.7",
    "del": "^5.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^6.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-if": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^6.2.0",
    "gulp-postcss": "^8.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.5",
    "gulp-zip": "^5.0.1",
    "vinyl-named": "^1.1.0",
    "webpack-stream": "^5.2.1",
    "yargs": "^13.3.0"
  }
}
```

**babelrc**

```
{
    "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env" ]
}
```

**gulfile.babel.js**

```
import { themeLocation } from './settings';
import gulp from 'gulp';
import yargs from 'yargs';

//styles
import sass from 'gulp-sass';
import cleanCSS from 'gulp-clean-css';
import gulpif from 'gulp-if';
import sourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';


//variables
config();
const PRODUCTION = yargs.argv.prod;


//STYLES
export const styles = () => {
    return gulp.src(`src/scss/bundle.scss`)
        .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.init()))
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulpif(PRODUCTION, cleanCSS({compatibility:'ie8'})))
        .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.write()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${themeLocation}/css`))
}
```

I would like to minify my css file on production, but it doesn't work. In my gulpfile file, I only see 
information:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'gulp-clean-css'. './node_modules/gulp-clean-css/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/gulp-clean-css` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'gulp-clean-css';`
```

I tried to install @types/gulp-clean-css but I got only some errors.

How can I solve my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Could you post errors received during installation of @types/gulp-clean-css?

Comment: @CristianTorres 

In my bash:

npm install @types/gulp-clean-css --save-dev
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @types/gulp-clean-css@latest

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     ..\_logs\2020-01-21T21_56_16_200Z-debug.log

Comment: @CristianTorres

in log:
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '@types/gulp-clean-css' ]
2 info using npm@6.4.1
3 info using node@v10.15.1
4 verbose npm-session 2fc2ec59f89dfcf0

5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fgulp-clean-css 203ms

Answer (score -1):

The package you need is: gulp-clean-css. Try with `npm install --save-dev gulp-clean-css`.

Comment: I added, but unfortunately still doesn't work. :/



+gulp-clean-css@4.2.0
updated 1 package and audited 8920 packages in 6.893s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: Does it returns the same error 
[code]
Could not find a declaration file for module 'gulp-clean-css'. './node_modules/gulp-clean-css/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm install @types/gulp-clean-css if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'gulp-clean-css'; 
[/code]?

Comment: Yes, it does. The comment is the same :/